# after running code it cannot produce the rock paper scissor

Tags: python

the code is about the rock paper scissor game but the computer is not able to generate the answer

```
print("press",0,"for rock")
computer_input=random.randrange(0,2)
print(items[player_input],"selected by player")
print(items[computer_input],"selected by computer")


if player_input==0 and computer_input==1:
    print("computer winner")
elif player_input==1 and computer_input==0:
    print("player winner")
elif player_input==1 and computer_input==2:
    print("computer winner")
elif player_input==2 and computer_input==1:
    print("player winner")
elif player_input==0 and computer_input==2:
    print("player winner")
elif player_input==2 and computer_input==0:
    print("computer winner")
else:
    print("both are winners")
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in the part "not able to generate the answer"?

Comment: For one, `player_input` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I think you are looking for the [input](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) function in order to get the player input, i.e. `player_input = input("press 0 for rock")`.

Comment: `print("both are winners")`  that's a very optimistic way of seeing a draw

Answer (score 0):

You are never asking the player for its input. In python, we do it with the [input](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) function.

Be careful, this function returns a string and you want to have an integer, so you have to convert it with the [int](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_int.asp) function.

With all of that, you just need to replace your first line `print("press",0,"for rock")` by `player_input = int(input("press 0 for rock"))`.

A last warning, you should check that the user entered a number between `0` and `2`. What should happen if the user is entering `5` or `"foo"`?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are your friends, so you can make the logic in dictionaries and make your code super simple and generic.

So if you want to play Sheldon's Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock or SMBC [Jonah-Moses-Noah](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/jonah-moses-noah) you just need to change the dictionary (which you could load from a JSON file and keep your code unmodified)

```
rules = {
    0: {
        0: "Both Win", 
        1: "Player Wins", 
        2: "Computer Wins"
    },
    1: {
        1: "Both Win", 
        2: "Player Wins", 
        0: "Computer Wins"
    },
    2: {
        2: "Both Win",
        0: "Player Wins", 
        1: "Computer Wins"
    }
}


while True:
    computer_input = random.choice(rules.keys())
    player_input = int(input(f"Choose one of this moves {rules.keys()} :"))
    try:
        print(rules[player_input][computer_input])
    except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
        print(f"Invalid input, allowed moves are: {rules.keys()}")
```